# basic arithmatic excercise unresponsive

Tags: javascript, html

the program is supposed to display two random int, check if the input receive is their multiplication, and respond properly. for some reason the ints never appear on screen, neither does the supposed response. on top of that, there is no error message in the debugger. would you please look at the code so I could understand why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>mental arithmatic</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function start(){

            var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*99 + 10);
            var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*99 + 10);
            var score = 0;

            document.getElementById("num1").innerHtml = num1;
            document.getElementById("num2").innerHtml = num2;

            var input = document.getElementById("input");
            var output = document.getElementById("output");
        }
        function pressed(){

            var res = parseInt(input.value);
            if(isNaN(res)){
                output.innerHtml = "please enter a number";
            }else{
                if(res == num1 * num2){
                    output.innerHtml = "correct! score - " + score;
                    score += 1;
                }else{
                    output.innerHtml = "false!";
                }
                start();
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <span id="num1"></span>x<span id="num2"></span>=<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="number"/><button id="finished" onclick="pressed()">V</button>

    <h5 id="output"></h5>

    <button onclick="start(); this.style.display = 'none';">start</button>

</body>
```

Comment: There's no element with id of `output` in the provided example. Notice also, that `NaN` is not equal to anything, not even itself.

Comment: h5 is that element. as for NaN, I will fix the bug, thank you. even so, that is not directly correlated to the error.

Comment: Hmm ... there it seems to be (now ..?) Anyway, `innerHtml` is a custom property, you probably meant `innerHTML`.

Comment: hmm, that seems to be the problem, and it was so frustrating. thank you.

Comment: The dup Quentin has linked points to the same mistake ...

Comment: should I delete the question then? well, that seems unnecessary. might as well leave it at that.

Comment: It's not necessary to delete the post, but this is your post, you can do what you do see the best.